# Using cx_freeze and pyGame to create a "stand-alone" package

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

Someone online mentioned "Python can be quite a hassle to get your stuff distributed in a way that everybody can just download and play, and that is basically what keeps me away from Python. I've searched the entire internet for proper solutions on that problem, but none were satisfying."

So far I have to agree with them. I haven't been able to "compile" (perhaps package is more accurate) my Python code that used pyGame into an exe file for Ubuntu.  The final step would be trying to get Windows and Mac OS working as well.

**I am using:
Python 2.7.6 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty**

***Sample game code to "compile" using cx_freeze:***

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30 # frames per second setting
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
catImg = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
catx = 275
caty = 150
direction = 'right'

while True: # the main game loop
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

    if direction == 'right':
        catx += 5
        if catx == 280:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        caty += 5
        if caty == 220:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        catx -= 5
        if catx == 10:
            direction = 'up'
    elif direction == 'up':
        caty -= 5
        if caty == 10:
            direction = 'right'

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(catImg, (catx, caty))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Shameless plug: for making a Windows installer, have a look at my [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) project, including [this pygame example](https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/tree/master/examples/pygame).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, will look into it. Any ideas why the above is not working with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

To compile python you need to create a new script called setup.

The code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable, re

build_exe_options = {"include_files" : ["cat.png"]}

setup(name = "name of program",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "",
      options = { "build_exe" : build_exe_options },
      executables = [Executable("name of program.py")]) # Program name
```

Place this code in the python file `C:\python\27` and put your program in with it, next go to command prompt and put `cd C:\python27` then `C:\python27\python.exe setup.py build` the executable will appear in the file build in the python folder.

Comment: This creates what appears to be a setup executable file, however, the file doesn't run when I click it.  (Also note I am using Ubuntu).  I also tried using cxfreeze nameofprogram.py and it produced similar results (i.e. dist folder with executable file not working).          Some of the errors I noted: Missing modules:
? PySide imported from cx_Freeze.macdist
? _sysconfigdata_d imported from _sysconfigdata
? apport_python_hook imported from sitecustomize
? cx_Freeze.re imported from __main__
? win32verstamp imported from cx_Freeze.freezer
? winreg imported from cx_Freeze.dist

Comment: nameofprogram.py is suppose to be your program. you have to change it to your programs name

Comment: Yes, I did change "nameofprogram.py" accordingly ;)

Comment: No. I always tried it the with the actual program name from the beginning. That's what I meant. It generated the dist folder but the setup file created doesn't run anything.

Comment: do you have `{"include_files" : ["cat.png"]}` in your setup script

Comment: If you open a terminal in the build directory and run `./nameofprogram`, you should see an error message or something.

Comment: I added the error I get. Also note that I am not getting a build directory, only a dist directory. Is that normal?

Comment: Where did you add that error? You will get a dist directory if you run `cxfreeze foo.py`, and a build directory if you make a setup.py file and run `setup.py build`.